# Using Apache Solr to index Nutch data

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am attempting to set up Solr to index the results from my Nutch crawler. The tutorials I have found online require the file conf/schema.xml to be copied from Nutch into Solr as part of the configuration, however this file does not exist in my version of Nutch. Is there another way to do this or is there something I am missing?
cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the ["official" Nutch tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/NutchTutorial):

> Note: due to [NUTCH-2745](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2745) the schema.xml is not contained in the binary package. Please download the [schema.xml](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/branch-1.16/src/plugin/indexer-solr/schema.xml) from the source repository.

NUTCH-2745 applies only to Nutch version 1.16 and will be fixed in 1.17.

Comment: Even in 1.17, after applying the xml in ./plugins/indexer-solr/schema.xml, the indexing fails. Only with managed mode it completes the indexing. However, with managed schema, query fails as it complains about undefined field _text_